# Gradle 1.12 - Why tasks are not executed

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradle wrapper to build my java project.

Recently I upgraded my gradle wrapper version from 1.0.3 milestone to 1.12.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

<Some extensions to java plugin tasks>
...

...

...

task package(type: Zip) {
    group = "Package"
    destinationDir = file("./install")
    baseName = "serverPackage"
    version = project.version

    into('someProject/bin') {
        from('./bin') {
            include '**/*.*'
        }
    }
    into('someProject/config') {
        from('./config') {
            include '**/*.*'
        }
    }
    into('someProject/config') {
        from('./src/main/resources') {
             include '**/*.*'
        }
    }
    into('someProject/lib') {
            from configurations.runtime
    }
}
```

When I run the command 'gradlew build' with the 1.12 version, for some reason (don't know why) the task **package** is not executed while in the 1.0.3 version it is executed.

**In version 1.0.3 it looks like this:**

```
:package
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:remoteInterfaceJar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

**While in the 1.12 version it looks like this:**

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes 
:jar 
:assemble 
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test 
:check 
:build 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Why does the **package** task is not executed in the 1.12 version?

Thx.

Comment: Impossible to say based on the given information. Some things to try: 1. Perform a clean build (always necessary after switching between Gradle versions) 2. Make sure that there is a task dependency on `package` 3. Delete `.gradle` directory

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the clean build and deleting the .gradle dir wasn't so helpful. What do you mean in task dependency on package? and why is it not necessary in the 1.0.3 version?  What other information is needed in order to make the question more clear?

Comment: Could you post the outputs from `--info` or `--debug`?

Comment: Please post all your tasks with their dependencies.

Comment: @yanish It could be a problem with the build script that only surfaces in 1.12. What I mean is that `build` has to (directly or transitively) depend on `package`. Try to figure out the intended chain of task dependencies leading from `build` to `package`.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @PeterNiederwieser, it seems that in version 1.12 you need to specifically tell gradle.build to run the task.  I solved it by adding the line: **build.finalizedBy package**

Comment: You'll likely want `build.dependsOn(package)` instead.